# Ruby on Rails & Prawn PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

Im creating a PDF Document on my Website.
All works just fine, but when i try to add a Image into the PDF i get
"We're sorry, but something went wrong.
We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly."

So something fails with Prawn.

This is how i try
"image 'logo.png"
i tryed so many ways, all found in the internet, nothing seemed to work.
One was with the BASEDIR, how do i know where BASEDIR is?

Anyway im using OSX Server 10.6 and id be very thankfull to anwser me those questions

-Where is the Prawn Logfile?
-How does one add a Image

Thanks very much, 
Greetings!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to refer to the full path to the file.

We usually refer to our images used in PDFs using the RAILS_ROOT as the starting point. So we use something like:

```
pdf.image "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/images/logo-header.png"
```

Assuming pdf is a Prawn::Document object.

Comment: I get an error trying to use this method. Any ideas? uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::RAILS_ROOT

Comment: In Rails 3 and beyond, RAILS_ROOT is deprecated in favor of Rails.root. You'll probably need to use that if you are using the latest Rails.